# Grey screen in Opera only using flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, opera, flutter-web-browser

Used flutter to build a web app, but I keep getting a grey screen in Opera. I know that this can happen with flutter if there is a UI error, but the website is working perfectly fine in Chrome, IE, Edge, and Safari. The console in developer mode gives me this error: "NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 're' on null". The "re" part of the error changes. I've seen it be "rg" and "rf", and google search has failed me when it comes to resolution. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't tell which browser feature exactly which is involved. But I can insinuate that there is a feature that Opera doesn't support but is crucial to Flutter web. And if you are familiar with web development, you will know that browser support is a big topic. caniuse.com would that have been helpful to confirm if it is a browser support issue. But here we can't tell the exact browser feature. Sorry about the above.

Answer (score 0):

If you specified rendered as HTML maybe that's the reason. Please build without specifying a renderer. Just use `flutter build web` and try once please

Comment: That's what I always use. I don't specify a renderer. It is hosted on firebase, but I don't think that makes a difference.

Comment: Okay great. Try building with flutter run -d web-server and run it in opera

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply. I have been trying to multiple things to get more information about the issue, but don't have more details.